# Strip off characters from xargs {} in bash

Tags: bash, substitution, xargs, string-substitution

Assume I have files named `"*.data.done"`. Now I want to rename them (recursively) back to "*.data" then ones which contains `"pattern"`

So here we go:

```
grep -l -R -F "pattern" --include '*.data.done' * | xargs -I{} mv {} ${{}::-5}
```

Well, this stripping of '.done' is not working (bash 4.3.11):

```
bash: ${{}::-5}: bad substitution
```

How can I do this most easiest way?

Comment: I'd create a tiny script: `for file in "$@"; do mv "$file" "${file%.done}"; done` in a file `moveit.sh` and then use `xargs sh moveit.sh`.  It's simple, and cleaning up the `moveit.sh` file isn't a huge overhead.

Comment: `{}` isnt a shell variable, you can't do shell paramter expansion on it.

Answer (score 4):

Placeholder `{}` cannot be used in BASH's string manipulations inside `${...}`.

You can use:

```
grep -lRF "pattern" --include '*.data.done' . |
xargs -I{} bash -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f/.done}"'
```

However if you want to avoid spawning subshell for each file then use a for loop:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do
    mv "$f" "${f/.done}"
done < <(grep -lRF "pattern" --include '*.data.done' --null .)
```